# Compile multiple js files into one minified file using IntelliJ IDEA 14

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, minify

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
├── index.html
├── scripts
│   ├── accordion
│   │   └── accordion.js
│   └── console
│       └── test.js
```

I want `accordion.js` and `test.js` to compile to a single minified file `scripts/site.js`. I've done this before with gulp but I'm trying to use IntelliJ. I already have YUI Compressor and it minifies the individual files no problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be possibile with file watchers. check this [minifying javascript with idea 14](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/minifying-javascript.html)

Comment: Thank you, I ended up just using python's webassets to compile everything.